# Scala - convert an array of Strings to Set[PhoneNumbers]

Tags: arrays, scala, list, set

I'm new in Scala, I have an List of allowed PhoneNumbers that I should get from a yaml file. I have it under my config file like that:

```
allowedPhoneNumbers:
  - 101111111001
  - 101111111002
  - 101111111003
```

I have an Config trait where I can take the list of allowed phone numbers from yaml file like that:

```
val allowedPN1= config.getStringList("allowedPhoneNumbers").toArray
```

or

```
def allowedPN2: util.List[String] = config.getStringList("allowedPhoneNumbers")
```

I've got an function that should return a Set[PhoneNumbers].
If I'm trying to return some

```
config.allowedPN1.toSet[PhoneNumbers]
```

It compiles fine but when I'm Building the project I get an

```
type arguments [PhoneNumbers] do not conform to method toSet's type parameter bounds [B >: Object]
```

So, how can I convert my list (taken from the config file) into some Set[PhoneNumbers]. Where PhoneNumbers is just a class that has an required pattern match.

```
case class PhoneNumbers(value: String) {
  require(Pattern.matches("\\d{12}", value),
    "The number must be a 12 digit phone number.")
  override def toString: String = value
}
```

Comment: What is your `PhoneNumber` class??

Comment: an class with an required pattern. I've put it in my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to peform a map operation first, to convert your strings to PhoneNumbers:

```
   val mySet = config.getStringList("allowedPhoneNumbers")
    .toList
    .map(PhoneNumbers(_))
    .toSet
```

Running a quick example:

```
scala> val lista = List("546452222222", "666666666666")
lista: List[String] = List(546452222222, 666666666666)

scala> lista.map(PhoneNumbers(_)).toSet
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[PhoneNumbers] = Set(PhoneNumbers(546452222222), PhoneNumbers(666666666666))
```

Comment: I've got an problem making a map from my Java util.List[String], because getStringList that reads from my config File is Java based and returns an List<String>

Comment: I have the same method in one project, we do a toList just after the getStringList method:


config.getStringList("fields").toList

I'll update my answer with that